# How i will show the data by using table by selecting option

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have add some value in ses lect option. If i select any option value then same data in table will show below of this form.
[image: this is screenshot of my page]

suppose as per image if i select the TR24BN then the all data of this option will show below this form as like a table.I have used here mysql,php and bootstrap.any help will be appricated.

Comment: You should used ajax post to send your option value then assign value to your form.

Comment: @Yash..thanks you..but please refer me any kind of solution..or proper way....

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Try using jQuery to make it easier for you. I will tell you what to do:

- Add a `change` event to that dropdown box. [Check the first example in this link](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- Inside that event, you need to use jQuery's [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) methods to send the dropdown's selected value to the server side page which will pull the data from the db and returns the contents. Then put the contents returned from the AJAX call to that textbox beneath that dropdown.

Hope this will help.